# Expected unqualified -id on line 25, How do I correct this?

Tags: c++, debugging

The error is on line 25 at the bracket. The program Reads,counts, and averages the values on file datafile.I don't know what it can be I've check for semicolons and everything in my code. It won't compile though.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;
    void  ReadAndSum(ifstream&, int&, float&); // Reads, counts, and averages the values on file dataFile.
    int main()
    {
        ifstream  dataFile;
        int  numberOfValues;
        float  average;
        cout << fixed << showpoint;
        dataFile.open("Averages.txt");
        ReadAndSum(dataFile, numberOfValues,average);
        cout << "The average of " << numberOfValues << " values is " << average  << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    void ReadAndSum(ifstream& dataFile, int& numberOfValues, float& average);
    {
        float number;
        numberOfValues = 0;
        average=0;
        dataFile >> number;
        while (dataFile)
        {
            average = average + number;
            numberOfValues++;
            dataFile>>number;
        }
        average = average/numberOfValues;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The line above `void ReadAndSum(ifstream& dataFile, int& numberOfValues, float& average);` ends with a semicolon, get rid of it and that should fix your problem.

Comment: no problem - probably just from copy/pasting the function prototype (happens to me all the time)